# Is there an easy way to switch from local project references to nuget packages?

Tags: .net, nuget, package-managers

In my current project we have several independent libraries that are used by +20 different systems.

Recently we decided to start managing our libraries using NuGet... we already published all libraries as nuget packages in an internal NuGet server and now we will start migrating our +20 apps to use these libs as nuget packages instead of local project references.

Is there an easy/automated way to make these changes?

Answer (score 2):

Run the `Install-Package` command for your packages on your projects and the references will be updated to the nuget packages directory (or whatever you configured it to be).

If your packages do more than simply adding a simple reference (e.g. the ASP.NET MVC package modifies the Web.config file) you'll have some undo to do, but it's generally a relatively painless way of updating .csproj references.

Answer (score 1):

I once wrote a PowerShell script for doing what you want (I think). Might be a place to start for you. This must be executed from the PowerShell console in Visual Studio. The two parameters are the project name and the corresponding package name.

```
param (
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $referencedProjectName,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $packageName
)



function Backup-File
{
    param ([parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $file)

    try
    {
        if (!(Test-Path $file))
            { throw "Could not find file $file" }

        $backup = $file + ".bak"

        if (Test-Path $backup)
            { Remove-Item $backup -Force }

        Write-Host "Backing-up $file"

        Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination $backup
    }

    catch
    {
        Write-Host "$($MyInvocation.InvocationName): $_"
    }
}



function Solution-Strip-Project-Reference
{
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $solutionFile,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $referencedProjectName
    )

    try
    {
        $regEx = '^Project\("\{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC\}"\)\s*=\s*"' + $referencedProjectName + '"'

        $content = Get-Content $solutionFile

        $newContent = @()

        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $content.Count; ++$i)
        {
            $line = $content[$i]

            if ($line -notmatch $regEx)
                { $newContent += $line; continue }

            do { ++$i; $line = $content[$i] } while ($line -notmatch "^EndProject$")
        }

        if ($newContent.Count -ne $content.Count)
        {
            Write-Host "Stripping project $referencedProjectName from solution $solutionFile"
            $newContent | Set-Content $solutionFile
        }
    }

    catch
    {
        Write-Host "$($MyInvocation.InvocationName): $_"
    }
}




function Solution-Get-Project-List
{
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $solutionFile
    )

    $projects = @()

    try
    {
        if (!(Test-Path $solutionFile))
            { throw "Could not find file $solutionFile" }

        $regEx = '^Project\("\{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC\}"\)\s*=\s*"(?<name>[^"]*)",\s*"(?<path>[^"]*)",\s*"(?<guid>[^"]*)"'

        $content = Get-Content $solutionFile

        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $content.Count; ++$i)
        {
            $line = $content[$i]

            if ($line -match $regEx)
            { 
                $name = $Matches['name']
                $projectPath = Resolve-Path $Matches['path'] -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

                if ($projectPath -eq $null -or !(Test-Path $projectPath))
                    { continue }

                $guid = $Matches['guid']
                $xml = [XML](Get-Content $projectPath)


                $project = New-Object Object |
                    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $name -PassThru |
                    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Path" -Value $projectPath -PassThru |
                    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Guid" -Value $guid -PassThru |
                    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "XML"  -Value $xml -PassThru

                $projects += $project
            }
        }
    }

    catch
    {
        Write-Host "$($MyInvocation.InvocationName): $_"
    }

    return $projects
}



function Project-Remove-Reference
{
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][object] $project,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][object] $referencedProject
    )

    try
    {
        $nm = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager -ArgumentList $project.XML.NameTable
        $nm.AddNamespace('x', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003')
        $projectNode = $project.XML.SelectSingleNode("/x:Project/x:ItemGroup/x:ProjectReference/x:Project[.='" + $referencedProject.Guid + "']", $nm)

        if ($projectNode)
        {
            $projectReferenceNode = $projectNode.ParentNode
            $itemGroupNode = $projectReferenceNode.ParentNode
            $itemGroupNode.RemoveChild($projectReferenceNode) | Out-Null
            $project.XML.Save($project.Path) | Out-Null
        }
    }

    catch
    {
        Write-Host "$($MyInvocation.InvocationName): $_"
    }
}



function Project-Install-Nuget-Package
{
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][object] $project,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $packageName
    )

    try
    {
        Install-Package -Id $packageName -ProjectName $project.Path
    }

    catch 
    {
        Write-Host "$($MyInvocation.InvocationName): $_"
    }   
}



function Project-Contains-Reference
{
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][object] $project,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][object] $referencedProject
    )

    $retVal = $null

    try
    {
        $nm = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager -ArgumentList $project.XML.NameTable
        $nm.AddNamespace('x', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003')
        $node = $project.XML.SelectSingleNode("/x:Project/x:ItemGroup/x:ProjectReference/x:Name[.='" + $referencedProject.Name + "']", $nm)
        $retVal = $node -ne $null
    }

    catch
    {
        Write-Host "$($MyInvocation.InvocationName): $_"
    }

    return $retVal
}



try
{
    $Error.Clear()

    Push-Location

    if (!(Get-Package $packageName -ListAvailable))
        { throw "Could not find package $packageName" }

    $path = Split-Path (Resolve-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName) -Parent

    $solutions = @(Get-ChildItem $path -Filter "*.sln" -Recurse)

    $solutions | foreach { 
        $solution = $_

        cd (Split-Path $solution.FullName -parent)

        $projectList = Solution-Get-Project-List $solution
        $referencedProject = $projectList | where { $_.Name -eq $referencedProjectName }

        if ($referencedProject -ne $null)
        {
            Backup-File $solution
            Solution-Strip-Project-Reference $solution $referencedProjectName

            foreach ($project in $projectList | where { Project-Contains-Reference $_ $referencedProject } )
            {
                Backup-File $project.Path
                Project-Remove-Reference $project $referencedProject
                Project-Install-Nuget-Package $project $packageName
            }
        }
    }
}

catch
{
    Write-Host "$($MyInvocation.InvocationName): $_"
}

finally
{
    Pop-Location
}
```